# Comparing two TreeMaps with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Trying to test that two `TreeMap`s are the same with the following code:

```
public class StreamTest {

  private Stream stream;
  private Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    stream = new Stream();
    map.put("this", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("is", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("an", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("just", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("example", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("file", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.put("for", new AtomicInteger(1));
    map.get("this").incrementAndGet();
    map.put("project", new AtomicInteger(1));
  }

  @Test
  public void lineToWordsToMapTest() {
    stream.getLines("testSampleFile");
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> sortedmap = new TreeMap<>(stream.getMap());
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> treemap = new TreeMap<>(map);  // Maps must be sorted in order to pass test
    Assert.assertEquals(treemap, sortedmap);
  }

}
```

And this is the puzzling error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.TreeMap<{an=1, example=1, file=1, for=1, is=1, just=1, project=1, this=2}> but was: java.util.TreeMap<{an=1, example=1, file=1, for=1, is=1, just=1, project=1, this=2}>
Expected :java.util.TreeMap<{an=1, example=1, file=1, for=1, is=1, just=1, project=1, this=2}> 
Actual   :java.util.TreeMap<{an=1, example=1, file=1, for=1, is=1, just=1, project=1, this=2}>
```

So the objects look like they are exactly the same using JUnit 4.12. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `AtomicInteger` doesn't override `equals()` and can't be successfully compared with other instance of `AtomicInteger` of the same value. You either need to change your map value type or write your own assertion for `AtomicInteger`.

To simplify:

```
Assert.assertEquals(new AtomicInteger(1), new AtomicInteger(1));
```

Results in:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger<1> but was: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger<1>
Expected :java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger<1> 
Actual   :java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger<1>
```

Comment: No. Write your own assertion that will call `AtomicInteger.get()`, you can't use assertions that are based on standard object equality when using `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Any pointer on how to do that? A link to an example of something like that? Should i just override the equals method?

Answer (score 1):

You have `get()` method for it

Gets the current value.

Returns:
the current value

What AtomicInteger::get guarantees is that when you call it, you will get the latest value available at the time of the call. A guarantee which you would not have with a plain int for example.